# play framework 2 ebean @manytoone Column specified twice

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, one-to-many, ebean, many-to-one

I'm running to some problems with ebean (using play framework 2 version 2.2.1)
I have two classes:

my graph class:

```
public class Graph extends Model {
     @Id
     @Column(name="id")
     private String id;

     @Column(name="type")
     private String type;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy="valGraph", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     private List<Val> valItems;
```

and my value class (with Val.graphId foreign key Graph.id):

```
public class Val extends Model
     @Id
     @Column(name="valId")
     private String valId;  

     @Id
     @Column(name="graphId")
     private String graphId;

     @Column(name="Key")
     private String Key;

     @Column(name="Value")
     private String Value;

     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name="graphId")
     private Graph valGraph;
```

but when trying to save a new item i get this error:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[Column 'graphId' specified twice]

Comment: possible duplicate of [PersistenceException, Column 'id' specified twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377478/persistenceexception-column-id-specified-twice)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377478/persistenceexception-column-id-specified-twice). I.e. Your `@Column(name="graphId")` and `@JoinColumn(name="graphId")` have the same name. Change one.

Comment: Donovan, Thank you for the fast answer,
i read the issue but don't understand something,

by changing the '@Column(name="graphId")' i get:
**Query threw SQLException:Unknown column 't0.graphId1' in field list**

and by changing the '@JoinColumn(name="graphId")' i get:
**javax.persistence.PersistenceException Unknown column 'graphId1'**

what am i not understanding here?

Comment: What database are you testing this on (H2, MySQL, etc.)? Did you apply the evolutions to recreate/update the tables? Sounds like you've changed you entities but your database schema has not been updated accordingly.

Comment: I'm using MySQL,
but my valGraph entity is just an entity i have in the java, that is not implemented in MySQL.
The Tables look like:
table Graph with string id (key), string type
and table Val with string valId (key), string graphId (forign key to id), String key, String value

Comment: Your `valGraph` property will be represented by a `graphId` column in MySQL by Ebean. However, you have defined your own `private String graphId` already. So you're confusing Ebean. I've explained this in more details [in this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377478/persistenceexception-column-id-specified-twice). Just remember, you should think in objects not SQL, let the persistence framework do it's job. In your case I would just remove your `graphId` property. You don't need it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After numerous searchers around the web I found this answer [here](https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/61) - thanks to jtal!

Just to summaries the problem:

Using Ebean i have made a @ManyToOne entity that is not implemented in the database in anyway,
even more the join field, in my case

> graphId

is a valid field that has values of its own.

when trying to join the column on that field, it will always fail because it creates this sql query:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
    Val;

select 
    t0.valId c0, 
    t0.graphId c1, 
    t0.Key c2, 
    t0.Value c3, 
    t0.graphId c4 <---- notice this duplicate
from 
    graph_val t0
```

in order to solve this, i tell ebean **not to use the second set of properties**.

my new ebean element looks like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="graphId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Graph valGraph;
```

and it works! =)

Comment: Update: Change name="graphId" to "graph_id". Thanks